# Global list of own class objects in Windows Forms C++

Tags: winforms, list, c++-cli

Ok, first I want to say, that my English isn't excellent :D

I'm writing a project in VS2013, in C++, Windows Forms.

I have 3 forms and 1 own class.

I didn't want to play with conversion text from textboxes(String^) to standard string, so I've done a public ref class:

```
public ref class Employee
{
    String^ FirstName;
    String^ Surname;
    String^ IDnumber;
    int Payment;
    int Age;
    bool Sex;
    String^ Phone;
    String^ Email;
    List<String^>^ Regions;
    List<String^>^ Skills;
    String^ Profession;
public:
    Employee(String^ FirstName, String^ Surname, String^ IDnumber, int Payment, int Age, bool Sex, String^ Phone, String^ Email, List<String^>^ Regions, List<String^>^ Skills, String^ Profession);
    Employee();
};
```

And now I'm trying to do a global generic list of objects of this class. I have no idea how to do it ;)

When I'm trying do

```
List<Employee^> list;
```

in MainWindow.cpp there is an error: a variable with static storage duration cannot have a ref class type

What should I do? Another list type? Do my class in another way?

//EDIT:

OK, I've done it as a member of MainWindow class:

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include "EmployeeCreator.h"
#include "OfferCreator.h"
#pragma once
namespace EmploymentAgency {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

public ref class MainWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MainWindow(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: W tym miejscu dodaj kod konstruktora
        //
    }
public: List<Employee^> lista;
....
```

And in second form EmployeeCreator I have:

```
#pragma once
namespace EmploymentAgency {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace EmploymentAgency;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Podsumowanie informacji o EmployeeCreator
/// </summary>
public ref class EmployeeCreator : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    EmployeeCreator(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: W tym miejscu dodaj kod konstruktora
        //
    }
public: MainWindow^ main;
```

I wanted to do (in MainWindow class):

```
private: System::Void AddEmployee_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    EmployeeCreator ^window = gcnew EmployeeCreator();
    window.main = this;  //it doesn't work
    window->ShowDialog();
}
```

For VS2013 in EmployeeCreator class MainWindow isn't a type:

"Missing ";" before "^" "

and if I include "MainWindow.h" there is to much files included.

Comment: List<> is a reference type so the variable must be declared with the ^ hat.  So it is `List<Employee^>^ list;`

Comment: Now is following error: a variable with static storage duration cannot have a handle or tracking reference type

Comment: Make it a member of a class, not a global variable.  Declare it *static* if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a static list of employees within the Employee class, it also elaborates on the use of `List<Employee^>^` when referencing the list.

```
    public ref class Employee {

        static List<Employee^>^  AllEmployees;

        void AddToAllEmployees()
        {
            if (!AllEmployees)
                AllEmployees = gcnew List<Employee^>();

            AllEmployees->Add(this);
        }

    public:
        System::String^ Firstname;
        System::String^ Surname;

        Employee(System::String ^firstname, System::String^ surname)
        {
            Firstname = firstname;
            Surname = surname;

            AddToAllEmployees();
        };

        Employee() {
            Firstname = "";
            Surname = "";

            AddToAllEmployees();
        }

        ~Employee() {
            if (AllEmployees)
                AllEmployees->Remove(this);
        };

        static List<Employee^>^  GetAllEmployees() { return AllEmployees; }
    };


    void testEmployeeClass() {
        Employee^ johnDoe = gcnew Employee("John", "Doe");
        Employee^ olaNordmann = gcnew Employee("Ola", "Nordmann");
        Employee^ nn = gcnew Employee();

        List<Employee^>^ everybody = Employee::GetAllEmployees();

        for each (Employee^ tmp in everybody) {
            // Do something _useful_ with the employees
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Employee: " + tmp->Firstname +" " + tmp->Surname);
        }
    }
```

My test functions displays the output to the debug window of Visual Studio 2013, but you surely have something more sensible to do with the list. In addition I've stripped down the Employee class to a bare minimum (and moved the members out into the public section) just to make the list handling more prominent.

Regards
Even

*Edit:* In the latter part of your question you are referring to a "MainWindow isn't a type"-error, and just to let you in on a little secret: The error messages provided by Visual Studio (and most compilers) often refer to an error earlier on. That is the error is not related to the MainWindow.h, but to something in front of the line listed for errors... *Do not only look on the line of the error, but also lines in front of the reported error line!*